# React InstantSearch : onSearchStateChange get the number of returned hits

Tags: reactjs, algolia, react-instantsearch

I am using the react instant search by algolia and i have a requirement to show an overlay every time there is result.

so i want to handle it via onSearchStateChange function provided by algolia. but i am still puzzled where to get the total hits. i already have an idea which is very quick like using the results displayed in the  by extracting the numbers via jquery. but i don't want to do it. is there other way you can suggest?

```
   onSearchStateChange(nextState) {

     //must get the number of total hits.

    nextState = cleanDeep(nextState);
    let filters = transformer(nextState);
    this.setState({
        searchState: nextState,
        filters: filters,
        searchChanged: true
    })
    this.sendToAti(filters);

    this.addOverlay(); // <--- function that will show the overlay.

    location.hash = qs.stringify(nextState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onSearchStateChange` function doesn't contain the `searchResults` object where you can find the number of hits.

However, we provide a `<Stats>` widget and a [`connectStats`](https://community.algolia.com/react-instantsearch/connectors/connectStats.html) connector that contain this information. Maybe you could use that?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, as pointed by @Marie and documented in the links she pointed, you need to follow a 3 step process:

1.- Create a custom component:

```
     export default function MyStatefullComponent({ searchResults  }){
            const hasResults = searchResults && searchResults.nbHits !== 0;
            const nbHits = searchResults && searchResults.nbHits;
            //Handle State Mutations Here
           
            return return (hasResults) ? <div className="shadow-xl mb-4 ml-4 p-8 ">
                                             Has Results
                                         </div>
                                         :
                                         <div>Has No Results</div>
            }
```

2.- connect to the component using the connector

Once you have your custom component, use the connectStateResults

```
import { connectStateResults  } from 'react-instantsearch-dom';

export default function OtherComponent(){  
    const StatefullComponent = connectStateComponent(MyStatefullComponent);

    return <StatefullComponent />
}
```

3.- import/add the component to your other component.